# Idiomatic way to wrap all responses in a standard object in Spring Boot 3.1.x

Tags: spring-boot

I am working on updating a project with a few thousand endpoints defined.

Each of theses endpoints uses something similar to:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/some/path", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<Whatever> someEndpoint() {
  Whatever whatever = someInjectedService.doStuff();
  return ResponseEntity.ok(whatever);
}
```

What I'd like to do is intercept the serialization of the `ResponseEntity` body and wrap it in a common `ResponseWrapper` class per some new requirements being handed down. The implementation of my wrapper is pretty simple where I just created it through the constructor, which is set up as `public ResponseWrapper(HttpStatus status, T body)`.

I have an `HandlerInterceptor` already set up that does some work; however, the serialization of responses does not appear to be something I can override there.

I was thinking of creating a custom `ObjectMapper` bean and sending it through; however, that doesn't give me the `HttpStatus` that is being sent back.

I'm thinking there's a much more idiomatic way to handle this but I simply don't know where it is.

My fallback right now is creating my own `ResponseEntity` object that extends the standard one and doing a find/replace on all the imports. While that would work just fine, it just feels like it's not the right approach in Spring Boot.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Two ideas, both with pros and cons:

1. Create an HTTP filter (javax.servlet.Filter) or an appropriate wrapper of the Spring framework and register it for every request that needs it;
2. Create an aspect and define a cutpoint to execute it around every method that is mapped to an endpoint.

Comment: AOP is certainly a option here. I was wondering if there's something more built-in. I think 3.1.x wants the Jakarta Filters and not the javax package, correct?

Comment: @eln00b correct.